# Multiple VMs on your local machine (Windows 10)

Tags: docker, hyper-v, swarm

I am new in using docker and I am trying to implement SWARM according to this tutorial - 
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#create-a-cluster

The tutorial starts with -

1. Launch Hyper-V Manager
2. Click Virtual Switch Manager in the right-hand menu
3. Click Create Virtual Switch of type External

I am using Windows 10 PRO and I cannot use Hyper-V Manager and Docker terminal at the same time. Because if I activate Hyper-V and then start docker terminal, my PC shows an error and shut down automatically.

So, I tried to create a virtual machine **without Hyper-V** by following code

```
$ docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "myswitch" myvm1
```

and as expected I got this error -

```
Wrapper Docker Machine process exiting due to closed plugin server (connection is shut down)
Error with pre-create check: "read tcp 127.0.0.1:50588->127.0.0.1:50587: wsarecv: `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."`
```

So, is there any alternative solution how can I proceed or to use Hyper-V Manager in Windows 10 without such problem.

Thanks a lot for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualbox and Hyperv don't work together. Since you are using `docker quickstart terminal` you should be using VirtualBox for the VM

```
$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox  swarmanager1
$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox  nodes1
$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox  nodes2
```

Once done you switch to manager node

```
$ eval $(docker-machine env swarmanager1)
$ docker swarm init --advertise-addr eth0
```

This will give you a token command and you need to execute them for each node

```
$ eval $(docker-machine env nodes1)
$ docker <swarm command from manager>
```